# How to rewrite a whole git history (squashing and rewording) without falling in conflicts?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history, git-squash

I am working on code base that has about 5000 commits (including merges). I started interactive rebase to squash similar commits and reword weak commit messages. Before that I deleted some big files following this [article](http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html).

Yet, I have conflicts starting from the 7th commit and conflicts 
go bigger commit by commit. Is there a way to do only operations that don't raise any conflicting changes?

I use the command:

```
git rebase FIRSTCOMMIT -i
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you can't generally easily rebase such history ad hoc. There might be workarounds depending on your situation. For example, if you have a tagged master you could squash changes between every tag into one commit. Similar strategy would work for any path connecting `FIRSTCOMMIT` and `HEAD` in general.